# Getting Cors policy error at api gateway when i try to access from angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors, microservices, api-gateway

When I try to access the microservice behind my API gateway through API gateway I am getting cors policy error for protected API but for unprotected API's it is working.
For security purposes, I m using keycloak for protected API requests diverted to keycloak with token but preflight request fails with "ERROR: Redirect"

**Note: backend code working fine as per requirement in postman but the issue is coming in angular frontend**

**below code is for API gateway yaml setup and security config respectively:**

```
>     app:
> 
>   config:
> 
>     keycloak:
> 
>       url: http://localhost:8180/auth
> 
>       realm: master
> 
>      
> 
> server:
> 
>   port: 8085
> 
>  
> 
> eureka:
> 
>   client:
> 
>     registerWithEureka: true
> 
>     fetchRegistry: true
> 
>     serviceUrl:
> 
>       defaultZone: http://localhost:8084/eureka/
> 
>  
> 
> spring:
> 
>   application:
> 
>     name: apigateway
> 
>   cloud:
> 
>     # A client sends a request to Spring Cloud Gateway. If the request matches a route through its predicates, the Gateway HandlerMapping
> will send the request to the Gateway WebHandler, which in turn will
> run the request through a chain of filters.
> 
>     gateway:
> 
>       **default-filters:
> 
>         - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin Access-Control-Allow-Headers
> 
>       globalcors:
> 
>         corsConfigurations:
> 
>           '[/**]':
> 
>             allowedOrigins: "*"
> 
>             allowedMethods: "*"
> 
>             allowedHeaders: "*"
>** 
>       # For automatic route discovery through Eureka
> 
>       discovery.locator:
> 
>         enabled: false
> 
>         lowerCaseServiceId: true
> 
>       # Route. It’s identified by a unique ID, a collection of predicates deciding whether to follow the route, a URI for forwarding
> the request if the predicates allow, and a collection of filters
> applied either before or after forwarding the request downstream.
> 
>       routes:
> 
>         - id: adminmodule
> 
>           uri: lb://adminms
> 
>           predicates:
> 
>             - Path=/adminapi/**
> 
>           filters:
> 
>             - RewritePath=/adminapi/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
> 
>         - id: appointmentmodule
> 
>           uri: lb://appointmentms
> 
>           predicates:
> 
>             - Path=/appointmentapi/**
> 
>           filters:
> 
>             - RewritePath=/appointmentapi/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
> 
>         - id: inboxmodule
> 
>           uri: lb://inboxms
> 
>           predicates:
> 
>             - Path=/inboxapi/**
> 
>           filters:
> 
>             - RewritePath=/inboxapi/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
> 
>         - id: patientmodule
> 
>           uri: lb://patientms
> 
>           predicates:
> 
>             - Path=/patientapi/**
> 
>           filters:
> 
>             - RewritePath=/patientapi/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
> 
>         - id: staticurl
> 
>           uri: http://localhost:8081
> 
>           predicates:
> 
>             - Path=/static-url/**
> 
>           filters:
> 
>             - RewritePath=/static-url/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
> 
>        
> 
>   security:
> 
>     oauth2:
> 
>       client:
> 
>         provider:
> 
>           keycloak:
> 
>             token-uri: ${app.config.keycloak.url}/realms/${app.config.keycloak.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token
> 
>             authorization-uri: ${app.config.keycloak.url}/realms/${app.config.keycloak.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/auth
> 
>             user-name-attribute: preferred_username
> 
>             user-info-uri: ${app.config.keycloak.url}/realms/${app.config.keycloak.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
> 
>             jwk-set-uri: ${app.config.keycloak.url}/realms/${app.config.keycloak.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
> 
>             user-info-authentication-method: header
> 
>         registration:
> 
>           apigateway:
> 
>             provider: keycloak
> 
>             client-id: apigateway
> 
>             client-secret: 7F8DqfFeTWxYv9pkvfrZ1XAxc2udVS0X
> 
>             authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
> 
>             redirect-uri: http://localhost:8180/login/oauth2/code/keycloak
> 
>             scope: openid
> 
>       resourceserver:
> 
>         jwt:
> 
>           jwk-set-uri: ${app.config.keycloak.url}/realms/${app.config.keycloak.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
> 
> 
> management:
> 
>   endpoints:
> 
>     web:
> 
>       exposure:
> 
>         include: '*'
> 
> logging:
> 
>   level:
> 
>     com.netflix: WARN
> 
>     org.springframework.web: DEBUG
> 
>     com.edu: DEBUG
```

**Security java file:**

```
@CrossOrigin(maxAge=3600)

@EnableWebFluxSecurity

@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity

public class SecurityConfiguration  {

       @Bean

       public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

 

              http.authorizeExchange()

//ALLOWING REGISTER API FOR DIRECT ACCESS

                           .pathMatchers("/adminapi/login/**").permitAll()

//ALL OTHER APIS ARE AUTHENTICATED

                           .anyExchange().authenticated().and().

                           csrf().disable().oauth2Login().

                           and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();

             

              http.cors();

              return http.build();

       }

 
}
```

**I tried almost all possible solutions on the internet, no solution worked for me.
Please help.**

Answer (score 0):

Did you set Proxy config from angular-cli?

Use the proxying support in the webpack development server to divert certain URLs to a backend server, by passing a file to the --proxy-config build option. For example, to divert all calls for http://localhost:4200/api to a server running on http://localhost:3000/api, take the following steps.

1. Create a file `proxy.conf.json` in your project's `src/` folder.
2. Add the following content to the new proxy file:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

3. In the CLI configuration file, `angular.json`, add the `proxyConfig` option to the `serve` target:

```
...
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
    },
...
```

4. To run the development server with this proxy configuration, call `ng serve`.

[more information about angular cli proxy](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)

Comment: tried but issue remains the same